# Accesos mediante Key Diccionarios Python

Tags: python, diccionarios

Quiero colocar alguna funcion en mi codigo que me permita introducir la Key del diccionario por fuera del codigo. Me refiero a ejecutar el programa y que a traves de la terminal me pregunte que key del diccionario quiero colocar.

Para expresarme mejor aca va parte del codigo:

```
d = (Inventory_data.get("Inventario_datos")).get("Alti DK $ 8 |")
```

Necesito que en la terminal cuando haya ejecutado mi programa, me pregunte donde esta `"Alti DK $ 8 |"`, cual Key quiero. EN este caso quiero `"Alti DK $ 8 |"` por eso esta escrito pero quiero algo asi:
TERMINAL:

```
(D:\Anaconda2) C:\Users\Marina\Desktop>python auto.py
Name of tag: Aca yo escribiria por ejemplo `"Alti DK $ 4 |"`
```

Y ahi comenzaria a ejecutrase todo el programa. Tambien si se puede hacer de alguna forma la misma funcion pero no solo introducir una sola key sino varias. Clave destacar que en caso de poder introducir muchas key necesito que todo el programa se base en la primera key, termine y luego inicie con la otra. No quiero que me ponga todas las key en mi funcion d

Otra forma que se me ocurre es creado una ventana en vez desde la terminal, pero necesito primero crear la accion que les pedi

Gracias

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import xlsxwriter
from Data_tags import Inventory_data

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Martin/Desktop/chromedriver')
d = (Inventory_data.get("Inventario_datos")).get("SS DK $ 8 |") #Elegir tag para crear a partir del Dic

while True:
    tag = input("Ingrese la clave deseada, nada para salir: ")
    if not tag:
        break  
    d = (Inventory_data.get("Inventario_datos")).get(tag, "Clave no encontrada")
    print(d)



def main():
    login("Usuario", "pass")
    NewTag("https://platform/en/users/inventory/create")
    Device = str(d.get("Li_platform")) #Mobile Web 
    Inicio_Li_Platform = ('//*[@id="platform_listbox"]/li[')
    Final_Li_Platform = (']')
    Platform(Inicio_Li_Platform+""+Device+""+Final_Li_Platform)
    NameTag(d.get("TagName"))
    Floor_Rate(d.get("Floor_price"))
    Save_Tag('save')
    Save_xlsx(d.get("Excel_name"))
    Inicio_Li_Publisher = ('//*[@id="publisher_listbox"]/li[')
    Final_Li_Publisher = (']')
    Publisher = str(d.get("Li_Publisher")) #Publisher Altitude
    Publisher_Li(Inicio_Li_Publisher+""+Publisher+""+Final_Li_Publisher)
    Tag_Rate_and_Save(d.get("Tag_Rate"))
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa simplemente un ciclo infinito y  `input` (Python 3) / `raw_input` (Python 2) para pedir la entrada del usuario:

```
while True:
    tag = input("Ingrese la clave deseada, nada para salir: ")
    if not tag:
        break  
    d = (Inventory_data.get("Inventario_datos")).get(tag, "Clave no encontrada")
    print(d)
```

[Ver en intérprete online.](https://repl.it/MSzT/0)

**Edición:**

Simplemente llama a tu función cada vez que el usuario introduce un tag válido:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import xlsxwriter
from Data_tags import Inventory_data

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Martin/Desktop/chromedriver')


def run(d):
    login("Usuario", "pass")
    NewTag("https://platform/en/users/inventory/create")
    Device = str(d.get("Li_platform")) #Mobile Web 
    Inicio_Li_Platform = ('//*[@id="platform_listbox"]/li[')
    Final_Li_Platform = (']')
    Platform(Inicio_Li_Platform+""+Device+""+Final_Li_Platform)
    NameTag(d.get("TagName"))
    Floor_Rate(d.get("Floor_price"))
    Save_Tag('save')
    Save_xlsx(d.get("Excel_name"))
    Inicio_Li_Publisher = ('//*[@id="publisher_listbox"]/li[')
    Final_Li_Publisher = (']')
    Publisher = str(d.get("Li_Publisher")) #Publisher Altitude
    Publisher_Li(Inicio_Li_Publisher+""+Publisher+""+Final_Li_Publisher)
    Tag_Rate_and_Save(d.get("Tag_Rate"))
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.close()

def main():
    while True:
        tag = input("Ingrese la clave deseada, nada para salir: ")
        if not tag:
            break  
        d = (Inventory_data.get("Inventario_datos")).get(tag, None)
        if d:
            run(d)
        else:
            print("Clave no encontrada.")

main()
```

Comment: Acabo de editar mi pregunta para ver si me puedes ayudar a incorporarla en el codigo.

Comment: @MartinBouhier dentro del while llama a tu función. He reestructurado un poco el código, mira a ver. Deberia funcionar sin problemas, logicamente no puedo reproducirlo, pero esa seria la idea.

Comment: Todo Perfecto amigo mio! Muchas gracias. Lo que si, si yo quisiera agregar mas de un campo a la misma vez, me refiero a algo asi: "Alti DK $ 4 |", "Alti DK $ 8 |", "Alti DK $ 10 |" cosa que se ejecute primero con "Alti DK $ 4 |", luego con el siguente y asi. Que deberia variar??

Comment: Se que una vez que termina con el primero me pregunta de nuevo cual campo quiero ingresar nuevamente pero quiero poner todos juntos